# What is a theretical way to write i++ in Dymola? And have hybrid continous and discrete model?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am just started to learn modelica and I have one (newbie) question. The problem for me is to change the way of thinking from convential programming thinking to modelica way of thinking.

I want to do simple program.
I have input array with PV output values in 5 minutes resolution.
I have input array with heat load values in 60 minutes resolution.
I have a energy storage that stores excess energy or takes energy fro  meeting the heat demand in real time.

I wrote this in openmodelica:

```
`class Add
 Real PV[:] = 100:10:1000;
 Real Heat[:] = 200:300:6000;
 Real Storage;
 Real p;
 Integer j;
 Integer i;
 Boolean power,heat;
 equation
 power=sample(0,5);
 heat=sample(0,60);
 when power then
 j=j+1;
end when;

when heat then
i=i+1;

end when;

Storage= PV[j] * 2.375-Heat[i];

p=Storage+ pre(p);

end Add;`
```

But when I c/p to dymola it gets an error on this " p=Storage+ pre(p); " part because it says pre() cannot be used for continuous model. When I delete pre() then it says it cannot devide by 0.

Can you explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.  Do you want `p` to be continuous or discrete?  Are you trying to integrate `p` or something.  It would be best if you included some equations.

Comment: I want storage to be cont. I don't actually need variable p but that is how it worked for me. I want to say Storage=Storage + PV[j]-Heat[j]
This is basic problem:
•A discrete series of heat demands, assumed to be constant over each time period (1 hour)
•A discrete series of inputs e.g. pv generation, again constant over each period but with a different period (5 min)
•A continuous conversion equation
•A continuous storage term
I don't have the exact equation for storing. I just want to mimic the continuous energy charging or discharging with inputs that are cont but change at specific times.

Comment: That doesn't really explain it but I think marcu1000s made the right assumption.  What you want to do is *integrate* the heat output over time to determine the total amount of energy consumed.  At least that's what marcu1000s did (very nicely), and I'm pretty sure that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. And I used Dymola to solve a simple example - I hope this works in OpenModelica, too.

If you are trying to use a time series of input data I would suggest using the model `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable`. In your case the table's first column would denote hourly timesteps, i.e. 0, 3600, 7200, ...; the second column could give values for the heat demand in kW, if it is constant at 300 kW like in your example this could mean 300, 300, 300, ...;

You can reference the output of the TimeTable model in equations using its RealOutput as `TimeTable.y`.

A very simple example for your test case could thus look like this:

```
model heatStorage

  Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.NonSIunits.Energy_kWh storage "Energy content of storage in kWh";

  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable solarThermal(table=[0,50; 3600,70; 7200,40; 10800,73]);
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable heatDemand(table=[0,300; 3600,300; 7200,300; 10800,
    300]);

equation
  der(storage) = (solarThermal.y - heatDemand.y)/3600;

end heatStorage;
```

I assumed time-varying output of a solar thermal collector. If you use PV to heat water you could include another variable and conversion equation. For the variable `storage` I used the definition of energy in kWh, therefore I divide the given equation by 3600. As Modelica is equation-based, writing `der(storage)` is the same as having the right side of the equation integrated. Thus, the calculated value for `storage` is the integral of the difference between input and output.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer.  This is what I suspected as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the starting info I was lookin for.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. As this example shows and you said yourself in the question, Modelica sometimes requires you to think a little different compared to other programming. And thank you Michael for the kind words to my solution.